# Second derivative of a matrix quartic form

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, derivatives, optimization

I need to compute the second derivative of the following quartic expression: $$x^H A^H x x^H A x$$ where is Hermitian. I have tried to compute the first derivative, and if I am not wrong, it should be: $$(A+A^H) x x^H (A+A^H) x$$
But then, I do not know how to proceed to calculate the second derivative. Could someone sketch the steps I need to follow? Thank you.

Comment: Did you compute the first derivative with respect to $x$ or $x^*$?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Define the scalar variables 
$$\eqalign{
&\phi &= x^HAx = (A^Tx^*)^Tx \cr
&\phi^* &= x^HA^Hx = (A^*x^*)^Tx \cr
&\psi &= \phi^*\phi \cr
}$$
Find the gradient of your function $(\psi)$  with respect to $x$, treating $x^*$ as an independent variable.
$$\eqalign{
d\phi &= (A^Tx^*)^T\,dx \cr
d\phi^* &= (A^*x^*)^T\,dx \cr
d\psi
 &= \phi\,d\phi^* + \phi^*\,d\phi \cr
 &= (\phi A^*x^* + \phi^*A^Tx^*)^Tdx \cr
g = \frac{\partial\psi}{\partial x}
 &= A^*x^*\phi + A^Tx^*\phi^* \cr
g^* = \frac{\partial\psi}{\partial x^*}
 &= Ax\phi^* + A^Hx\phi \cr
}$$
Not that we need it, but the last equation is a consequence of the fact that $\psi=\psi^*\,$ (it's real).

Now the Hessian is just the gradient of the gradient, so
$$\eqalign{
dg
 &= (A^*x^*)\,d\phi + (A^Tx^*)\,d\phi^* \cr
 &= \Big((A^*x^*)(A^Tx^*)^T + (A^Tx^*)(A^*x^*)^T\Big)\,dx \cr
H = \frac{\partial g}{\partial x}
  &= A^*x^*x^HA + A^Tx^*x^HA^H \cr
}$$
Note that the Hessian is symmetric, but it is not Hermitian.

Comment: A question with respect to $d\psi = (\phi A^*x^* + \phi^*A^Tx^*)^Tdx \Rightarrow g = A^*x^*\phi + A^Tx^*\phi^* $. What rule did you apply that $\phi A^*x^*$ became $A^*x^*\phi$? Am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: Since $\phi$ is a scalar, you can move it anywhere you like. It was convenient to move it to the end of the expression, to prepare for the subsequent step of calculating $dg$

Comment: Oh yes, makes sense... thanks for the clarification, greg!

Answer (score -1):

The *second derivative* of a multi-variable function $f=f(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$ is usually expressed as its Hessian matrix
$$
Hf(x_1,\ldots,x_n)=\left(\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x_i\partial x_j}\right)_{i,j=1}^n
$$
Here
$$
f(x)=x^tA^txx^tAx=(x^tBx)^2, \quad \text{where $B=\frac{1}{2}(A+A^t)=(b_{ii})$}.
$$
Hence
$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}=4(x^tBx)(Bx)_i
$$
and 
$$
\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x_i\partial x_j}=8(Bx)_i(Bx)_j+4(x^tBx)b_{ij},
$$
and thus
$$
Hf(x)=8Bx(Bx)^t+4(x^tBx)B
$$

Comment: $x$ is a complex variable.

Comment: What is $x^H$? Is it the conjugate of the transpose, or just the transpose?

Comment: Hermitian = conjugate transpose.

Comment: Unfortunately, you CAN NOT differentiate the conjugate. The function $f(z)=\overline{z}$ is NOT analytic! Hence, the conjugate applies only to matrix (if at all).

Comment: You are wrong! We can differentiate over the complex without any problem.  See  Hjorungnes' paper https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?tp=&arnumber=4203075

Comment: You are suggesting an Engineering paper. I am a professor of Mathematics. I am afraid, I am not wrong. You CAN NOT differentiate $f(z)=\overline{z}$. Ask your Professor of Mathematics.

Comment: What??? A paper with more than 350 citations and we says it is wrong?? Are you kidding? Actually, we do not know complex derivatives and you do not accept this fact. The derviatives of $f(z) = z^{*}$, using  Hjorungens' approch are $\frac{\partial f(z)}{\partial z} = 0$ and $\frac{\partial f(z)}{\partial z^{*}} = 1$. See also his book in https://epdf.tips/complex-valued-matrix-derivatives-with-applications-in-signal-processing.html

Comment: $\frac{d\overline{z}}{\partial z}=0$! - Talk to a mathematician in your Department.

Comment: Ok! The book is wrong, and all research made based on this approach is wrong. Congratulations!!

Comment: Ask somebody, who is a Mathematician (this is a Mathematics site), is $f(z_1,\ldots,z_n)=|z_1|^2+\cdots+|z_n|^2$ is differentiable in $\mathbb C$. This is what you get if $A=I$.

Comment: @YiorgosS.Smyrlis I suppose they are talking about Wirtinger derivatives, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wirtinger_derivatives

Comment: Thank you for the replies. I will take a look to that paper.

Comment: @AlexSilva The standard complex derivative of  $f(z) = \overline{z}$ does not exist. You can define the differential operators $\frac{\partial}{\partial z} = \frac12\left(\frac\partial{\partial x} + \frac1i\frac\partial{\partial y}\right)$ and $\frac{\partial}{\partial \overline{z}} = \frac12\left(\frac\partial{\partial x} - \frac1i\frac\partial{\partial y}\right)$, and these give you a way to "differentiate" a non-analytic function in a sense, but it does not allow you to take the complex derivative of a function that is not complex differentiable.

Comment: @AlexSilva In particular, the complex derivative of a function $f$ exists if and only if $\frac{\partial f}{\partial \overline{z}} = 0$, while $\frac{\partial \overline{z}}{\partial \overline{z}} = 1$. So $\overline z$ is not complex differentiable.

Comment: @Monstrous Moonshiner, this is the proposition of Hjorungnes’ approach: make a non analytic function differentiable by redefining the differential operators. I wasn’t discussing about whether $z^*$ were “differentiable” in a standard way, but that there was a way to differentiate complex functions ( including $z^*$) as it was asked by the OP, which was denied by Yorgos. Probably, it was a misunderstanding.